# Confgure Speedment without UI?

Tags: orm, java-8, java-stream, speedment

I just found out about [Speedment](http://www.speedment.com/), a Java 8 Stream-based OR/M library, and have to say that I love the *idea* of it. No more crazy configurations or spending time sifting through 900 pages of Hibernation docs to find the right way to annotate my classes: Speedment just reads your database, generates Java classes for you and gives you a stream-based API to run DDL statements against them. Wicked cool.

**However**, the one big deal breaker is that it *seems* like you *have* to use the Speedment UI for configuring your DB connection. Furthermore, the docs don't seem to specify how you can do things like:

- Specify which tables you want code generated against (maybe there's a few tables inside a database that you *don't* want models generated for
- Execute stored procedures
- Configure in-memory caches

etc. Looking on GitHub I can't seem to find how the code is wired together from the UI to produce a configuration object. Just wondering if there's a way to configure Speedment sans UI (perhaps via JSON or YAML), and if so, what configurations are available.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to configure Speedment without the UI, but it requires some tinkering. Basically, to generate code from a database, you need to manually create a *speedment.json*-file and specify which schema to generate from manually.

1. Create a new Maven Project (a `pom.xml`-file and a `src/main/java`-directory).
2. Create a file `/src/main/json/speedment.json`
3. Enter the following:

```json
{
  "config" : {
    "name" : "yourproject",
    "packageName" : "com.yourcompany",
    "packageLocation" : "src/main/java/",
    "dbmses" : [{
      "name"      : "db0",
      "typeName"  : "MySQL",
      "ipAddress" : "127.0.0.1",
      "port"      : 3306,
      "schemas" : [{
        "name" : "your_db_schema"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

4. Run the Maven goal: `mvn speedment:reload -Ddbms.username=root -Dbms.password=password` (with the credentials for your database)
5. Finally, run the Maven goal: `mvn speedment:generate`

The first goal connects to the database and fills in any missing configuration details in the .json file. The second goal generates .java-code.

To disable a specific table, set the json-property "enabled" to `false`. Youc an also disable individual columns this way.

If you want, you can now configure the generation directly in the .json-file and then regenerate.